# Get user Phone number in ionic app

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic.I'm Developing app which can automatically get user phone number. 
I have used https://github.com/oneminutedistraction/phonenumber this plugin. 
Is There any plugin available which can help me out?

Comment: Did you tried getting phone number using the mentioned plugin ? Its pretty straight.

Comment: It seems easy to use thats true.
but um not getting with it... i don't know why ?? :(
@atulquest93

Comment: Is there any error you are getting while working with that plugin ?

Comment: On most devices it's not possible to get the phone number, you are testing in one of those devices, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: it could be @jcesarmobile

Comment: used this code
`window.plugins.phonenumber.get(success, failed);

function success(phonenumber) {
    console.log("My number is " + phonenumber);
}
function failed(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
`
seccess not worked but failed called everytime  @KirankumarDafda